# Sub-group finding

Tags: awk

I have this kind of records (rows):

```
0 1 4 8 2 3 7 9 3 4 8 9 4 7 9 1 0 0 2 5 8 2 4 5 6 1 0 2 4 8 9 0
```

Definitions:

- group: collection of numbers which are separated by 0-s (zeros)
- sub-group: collection of numbers which are separated by local minima in the groups
- local minimum: the numbers before and after it are greater

In the above example there are 3 groups and 7 sub-groups, i.e.

- groups: 1 4 8 2 3 7 9 3 4 8 9 4 7 9 1 , 2 5 8 2 4 5 6 1 , 2 4 8 9
- sub-groups: 1 4 8 , 3 7 9 , 4 8 9 , 7 9 1 , 2 5 8 , 4 5 6 1 , 2 4 8 9 (this last is identical to the group itself)

So, in these kind of records I have to

- find the minima (print out: 2, 3, 4, 2)
- the size (number of character) of these sub-groups
- positions of numbers of the sub-groups in the groups

I have already started to write something, but I am stuck here...

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Here is the code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    db = split($0,a,/( 0)+ */)
    for (i=1; i<=db; i++) {
        split_at_max(a[i])
        for (j=1; j<=ret_count; j++) {
            print ""
            for (k=1; k<=maximums[j]; k++) {
                print ret[j,k]
            }
        }
    }
}

function split_at_max(x) {

    m_db = split(x,values," ")
    for (mx in ret) {
        delete ret[mx]
    }
    ret_count = 1
    ret_curr_db = 0
    for (mi=2; mi<m_db; mi++) {
        ret_curr_db++
        ret[ret_count,ret_curr_db] = values[mi-1]

        if ( (values[mi-1] <= values[mi]) &&
              (values[mi] >= values[mi+1]) &&
              (values[mi+1] <= values[mi+2]) ) {
            maximums[ret_count] = ret_curr_db
            ret_count++
            ret_curr_db = 0
        }
    }
    ret_curr_db++
    ret[ret_count,ret_curr_db] = values[mi-1]
    ret_curr_db++
    ret[ret_count,ret_curr_db] = values[mi]

    maximums[ret_count] = ret_curr_db

}
```

Comment: nice post, BUT please edit it to include expected sample outputs. Also, looking more closely at your problem, consider that a typical unix/awk solution will reformat data into standardized formats per type of record to process. Make your code create files for each of your use cases. Much easier. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interesting assignment.

wrote a quick and dirty awk script. there should be a lot of room to optimize. I don't know what kind of output are you expecting...

```
awk -v RS="0" 'NF>1{

delete g;
print "group:";
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        printf $i" ";
        g[i]=$i
    } 
    print "";
    t=1;

    delete m;

    for(i=2;i<length(g);i++){
        if(g[i-1]>g[i] && g[i]<g[i+1]) {
            print "found minima:"g[i]
            m[t]=i;
            t++;
            }
    } 
    if(length(m)>0){
    s=0;

    for(x=1;x<=length(m);x++){
            printf "sub-group: "

        for(i=s+1;i<m[x];i++){
            printf g[i]" "
            s=m[x];
        }

        print "";
        if(x+1>length(m)){
            printf "sub-group: ";
            for(i=s+1;i<=length(g);i++)
                printf g[i]" "
            print "";
        }
    }
    }else{
    print "no minima found. sub-group is the same as group:"
    printf "sub-group: "
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        printf $i" ";
        g[i]=$i
    } 

}
    print "\n-----------------------------" 
} yourFile
```

the output on your example input:

```
group:
1 4 8 2 3 7 9 3 4 8 9 4 7 9 1 
found minima:2
found minima:3
found minima:4
sub-group: 1 4 8 
sub-group: 3 7 9 
sub-group: 4 8 9 
sub-group: 7 9 1 

-----------------------------
group:
2 5 8 2 4 5 6 1 
found minima:2
sub-group: 2 5 8 
sub-group: 4 5 6 1 

-----------------------------
group:
2 4 8 9 
no minima found. sub-group is the same as group:
sub-group: 2 4 8 9 
-----------------------------
```

**update**

fixing for those "special" elements like 20,30,40...

still quick and dirty:

change my awk script above to

```
sed 's/^0$//g' yourFile | awk -v RS="" [following codes are the same as above]......
```

then the output is:

```
group:
6 63 81 31 37 44 20 
found minima:31
sub-group: 6 63 81 
sub-group: 37 44 20 

-----------------------------
```

Comment: Can we "hack" somehow to be usable for this kind of records too: 0 6 63 81 31 37 44 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ?

Comment: I see what you meant, the "20" right? see the update in my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, cool! Just another short question: I would like to get the weighted sum (average position) the sub-group record by record. The definition of the weighted sum: (sum of sub-group numbers) * (position of sub-group numbers in the recrod) / (sum of sub-group numbers). For example: sub-group --> 1 4 8 in group 0 0 1 4 8 2 3 7 9 0 0 --> 3*1+4*4+5*8/(1+4+8), because the actual positions of the numbers of sub-group "1 4 8" in the recrod are 3, 4, 5 if we begin count from 1. The beginning two 0-s have position in the recrod 1, 2.                         --> I need this record by record

Comment: In the last example 0 6 63 81 31 37 44 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    I would expect something like this output                             group:
6 63 81 31 37 44 20 center: 4.8581
found minima:31
sub-group: 6 63 81  center: 3.5
sub-group: 37 44 20 center: 6.8316

Comment: Hi! Can you help me a little, in the last case (containing 20 in the group) you wrote I did not get the desired output as before the other cases...

Comment: The problem is this part: 20 0 . In this case I get back only 2,  not 20 in the subgroup...

Comment: this was already fixed two days ago. have you tried my updated answer? note since there is a sed at beginning to preprocess your input file and pipe to awk, you should remove the input filename after the awk line. the output is in answer as well.

Comment: Hi, just returning to this exercise, I would like to know, what about this line: 0 5 17 5 0 0 0              If I would like to get only the minima, this is printed out too, BUT 5 17 5 are not minima at all. Can you help me?